# Parsing a string address into little endian

Tags: c, string-parsing, libc, endianness

My partner and I are attempting a return-to-libc exploit in C and a step we're having to deal with is parsing an address given in string format to little endian.

So for example, we are given in string form an address that looks like:

```
"ffffb4a2"
```

Which needs to end up looking like:

```
"\xa2\xb4\xff\xff"
```

So we can feed it back into our program for the rest of the exploit. With a clever use of memcpy like:

```
memcpy(subbuff1, &address[6], 2);
subbuff1[2] = '\0';
memcpy(subbuff2, &address[4], 2);
subbuff2[2] = '\0';
.....strcat(subbuff1, subbuff2);
```

and some proper null terminators we can get something that looks like:

```
"a2b4ffff"
```

Which our program doesn't like at all. Using "\x" in any sort of capacity we've tried causes it to have a minor freakout. I'm sure there's a simple way to do this but my partner and I are struggling.

Is there a simple way to parse an address like this into Little Endian?

Comment: sprintf() or snprintf() The manual is your friend.

Comment: Do you want "\xa2\xb4\xff\xff" or "a2b4ffff"? If it's an address in string format why do you use \x to convert the following hex values to single chars? The string "\x41\x62" defines a string "Ab". Also, you have assumed that "ffff" will not need swapping, but in the case of (say) "ffee" it would.

Comment: Reading manual pages is a skill all by itself. I'll spend some time working with snprintf() and see what I find.

Answer (score 2):

Just read it as a hexadecimal number of sufficient length, or use the proper format for pointers:

1. [`strtoll`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)

   ```
   long long n = strtoll(yourstringhere, 0, 16);
   void* p = (void*)n;
   ```
2. [`sscanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

   ```
   void* p;
   sscanf(yourstringhere, "%p", &p);
   ```
3. Or embed the hexadecimal literal:

   ```
   0xffffb4a2
   ```

Comment: This has not addressed the requirement to swap Endian format

Comment: @WeatherVane: I guess their target is little-endian, in which case we are done.

Comment: OP has specifically shown his input and output string representations opposite ways round.

Comment: @WeatherVane: "`ffffb4a2`" that's their printed string. Parsed as a number, that's `0xffffb4a2`. Now if their target is little-endian, those 4 octets will be stored like `a2 b4 ff ff`. Little endian.

Comment: This...might be what I'm looking for. I'm not entirely sure because like Deduplicator said it doesn't seem to be little endian. We're currently playing around with this.